# Java SWING Jbutton setEnable

Tags: java, swing

I added enable to click on my button only once, but this time the color I set in the foreground did not work. It gives me another color (pale white).

```
jButton1.setText(startGame);

if (turn % 2 == 0) {
  
    jButton1.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 56)); 
    jButton1.setFont(new Font("myf", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    jButton1.setEnabled(false); // 
    turn++;
} 
else {
    jButton1.setForeground(new Color(255, 22, 22)); 
    jButton1.setBackground(new Color(255, 22, 22)); 
    startGame = "O"; // 
    jButton1.setText(startGame); // 
    jButton1.setFont(new Font("myf", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    jButton1.setEnabled(false); 
    turn++;
}
```

When I press the button, I expect a green letter to appear, but a pale white color appears.

Comment: *but a pale white color appears.* - the disabled text color is determined by the LAF. Depending on your lAF you may be able to change this property for all buttons that are disabled. See [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). Look for the appropriate "disabled" property for your LAF. Also, Color objects can be shared, so there is no need to create a unique instance for each property you want to set.

Comment: Another option might be to use the [Text Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/text-icon/) class to create an Icon for the button. You can't control the Color and Font of the Icon. Then you use the `setDisabledIcon(...)` to set the icon when disabled. Note however, that you also need to use the `setIcon(...)` method in order for the disabled icon to display. So you would likely need to create two TextIcons. One for each state.